# Numerate cells in a cube

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

to create cubes. However I would like to numerate the cells inside the cube. Any idea how I could do it?

[image]

Comment: Can draw a sketch which numbers should go where?

Comment: @samcarter Updated

Comment: If you need isometric-view labels on the sides, these questions are relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302539/putting-labels-on-a-cube-with-perspective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a simple `foreach`-loop. The only tricky thing is to define the vertical cells in reversed order (`2-\y`) so that maths can do its magic to number the cells.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4); %horizontal front
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4); %vertical front
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}

\foreach \x in{0,...,3}{    
    \foreach \y in{0,...,3}{
        \node[] at (\x-1,2-\y) {\pgfmathprint{int(\x+4*\y)}};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]