# improve code - formulas in perspectives and rotated

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I want to reproduce the next image or improve it, that has depth and an effect of small points like stars.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-10pt,-10pt) rectangle (610pt,310pt);

\fill[black!95!white] (0,0) rectangle (600pt,300pt);

\node[rotate=45,white] at (80pt,50pt)  {$ \vec{F}=m\vec{a} $};
\node[rotate=-45,white] at (550pt,50pt)  {$ e=m c^2 $};

\node[rotate=45,white] at (50pt,100pt)  {$ \vec{F}=m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} + \vec{v}\frac{dm}{dt} $};
\node[rotate=-45,white] at (520pt,100pt)  {$  \vec{F}_g=-F\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \vec{e}_r $};

\node[rotate=45,white] at (70pt,150pt)  {$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} $};
\node[rotate=-45,white] at (550pt,150pt)  {$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = 2 $};

\node[rotate=10,white] at (100pt,250pt)  {$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x $};
\node[rotate=-10,white] at (500pt,250pt)  {$ \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x} $};

\node[rotate=60,white] at (200pt,150pt)  {$ x = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}} $};
\node[rotate=15,white] at (350pt,100pt)  {$ \mathbf{X} = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    x_1 & x_2 & \ldots \\
    x_3 & x_4 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
    \end{array} \right) $};
\node[rotate=20,white] at (400pt,250pt)  {$  2H_2 + O_2 {\overset{n,m}{\longrightarrow}} 2H_2O $};

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

It should look similar to this image.

[image]

Comment: The only package that I know that is able to do that is `asymptote`, so you may want to consider tagging this question `asymptote`. (Perspective drawing *is* possible with Ti*k*Z, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/aligning-a-text-in-3d-diagram/447120#447120, but AFAIK you cannot "distort" the characters in the way shown in your screen shot.)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208426/how-do-i-display-pi-in-latex-like-don/208428#208428, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301897/star-wars-text-effect/302908#302908, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228579/tikz-perspective-letter-rotated-writing, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302539/putting-labels-on-a-cube-with-perspective, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319172/gimp-like-perspective-transform-in-tikz, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192620/plot-3d-stacked-squares-with-shadow

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Among all your links, only https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319172/gimp-like-perspective-transform-in-tikz has a perspective view, and it was used in my above link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447114/aligning-a-text-in-3d-diagram/447120#447120. However, AFAIK it will be *extremely* hard to type formulae using these tricks since you need to position characters at explicit coordinates. On the other hand, `asymptote` does everything for you.

Comment: @marmot It is possible to give an example of perspective with a formula using asymptote since it is not clear to me how to use it.

Comment: @SamuelDiaz I am not writing answers to posts with accepted answers. (I am not saying you should unaccept the answer! All I want to say is that you seem to have gotten what you wanted, so there is no need to add another answer. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my answer here: [Placing text on face of 3d cube](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254010/placing-text-on-face-of-3d-cube?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In this case I use an **isometric view (not perspective)** with axis at +/-30 degrees and a 90 degree vertical.  However, if each formula is small enough relative to the overall field, then you might be able to adjust each formula to make is singularly isometric with the overall perception as (nearly) being in perspective.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,fp}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand\slbox[2]{%
  \FPdiv{\result}{#1}{57.296}% CONVERT deg TO rad
  \FPtan{\result}{\result}%
  \slantbox[\result]{#2}%
}%
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][30]{%
        \mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\rotslant[3]{\rotatebox{#1}{\textcolor{white}{\slbox{#2}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-10pt,-10pt) rectangle (610pt,310pt);

\fill[black!95!white] (0,0) rectangle (600pt,300pt);

\node at (80pt,50pt)  {\rotslant{30}{30}{$ \vec{F}=m\vec{a}$}};
\node at (550pt,50pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{30}{$ e=m c^2 $}};

\node at (50pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{30}{30}{$ \vec{F}=m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} + \vec{v}\frac{dm}{dt} $}};
\node at (520pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{-30}{$\vec{F}_g=-F\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \vec{e}_r $}};

\node at (70pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{30}{-30}{$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} $}};
\node at (550pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{-30}{$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = 2 $}};

\node at (100pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{30}{-30}{$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x $}};
\node at (500pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{-30}{$ \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x} $}};

\node at (200pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{30}{30}{$ x = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}} $}};
\node at (350pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{30}{$ \mathbf{X} = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    x_1 & x_2 & \ldots \\
    x_3 & x_4 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
    \end{array} \right) $}};
\node at (400pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{-30}{$  2H_2 + O_2 {\overset{n,m}{\longrightarrow}} 2H_2O $}};

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is what I was referring to with **faux perspective**, by manually setting the rotation on individual equations:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,fp}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand\slbox[2]{%
  \FPdiv{\result}{#1}{57.296}% CONVERT deg TO rad
  \FPtan{\result}{\result}%
  \slantbox[\result]{#2}%
}%
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][30]{%
        \mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\rotslant[3]{\rotatebox{#1}{\textcolor{white}{\slbox{#2}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-10pt,-10pt) rectangle (610pt,310pt);

\fill[black!95!white] (0,0) rectangle (600pt,300pt);

\node at (80pt,50pt)  {\rotslant{43}{43}{
  $ \vec{F}=m\vec{a}$}};
\node at (550pt,50pt)  {\rotslant{-35}{35}{
  $ e=m c^2 $}};
\node at (50pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{38}{38}{
  $ \vec{F}=m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} + \vec{v}\frac{dm}{dt} $}};
\node at (520pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{-40}{-40}{
  $\vec{F}_g=-F\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \vec{e}_r $}};
\node at (70pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{32}{-32}{
  $ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} $}};
\node at (550pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{-32}{-32}{
  $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = 2 $}};
\node at (100pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{20}{-20}{
  $ \frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x $}};
\node at (500pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{-25}{-25}{
  $ \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x} $}};

\node at (200pt,150pt)  {\rotslant{42}{42}{
  $ x = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}} $}};
\node at (380pt,100pt)  {\rotslant{-39}{39}{
  $ \mathbf{X} = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    x_1 & x_2 & \ldots \\
    x_3 & x_4 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
    \end{array} \right) $}};
\node at (400pt,250pt)  {\rotslant{-30}{-30}{
  $  2H_2 + O_2 {\overset{n,m}{\longrightarrow}} 2H_2O $}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To have these projections, you'd only need to load the 3d library and use sth like `\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape] \node{text}; \end{scope}`. There are zillions of answers of this type. The problem is: this is *not* perspective drawing.

Comment: @marmot I never claimed they were perspective (in fact, I specifically denied it), though I have emphasized that point now.  And as I am not a `tikz` user, I will have to leave that to others.

Comment: I did not say you claimed it was perspective but I just wanted to tell you that there is a much simpler way to achieve your output. And I told you what the limitations of this approach are. You can mitigate them by using `decorations.text` to vary the size of the characters along paths, but AFAIK this does not work with formulae.

Comment: @ StevenB.Segletes your construction meets the perspective of the formulas, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a too serious answer, but just to substantiate my statement that such things can be done very easily with asymptote. (You need to run e.g. with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyPers}
import labelpath3;
size(8cm,8cm);
settings.render = 4;
currentprojection = perspective((-0.5,4,0.1), up=Z,autoadjust=true);
currentlight=(2,15,5);
material pens =  material(diffusepen=0.7blue,ambientpen=blue,emissivepen=0.9*white,specularpen=0.95white,shininess=0.95);
draw(scale(0.8,1,-1)*labelpath("$\displaystyle B(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\,\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}$",
(2*Y+X-Z) -- X-Z),pens);
path3 Back=scale3(3)*plane(X,Z,O);
draw(surface(Back), black);
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And before I forget: there are, of course, dedicated Ti*k*Z packages and libraries to do the projections.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\dd}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\clip(-10pt,-10pt) rectangle (610pt,310pt);

\fill[black!95!white] (0,0) rectangle (600pt,300pt);
%\tdplotsetmaincoords{90+30*sin(\X)}{\X}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90+30*sin(40)}{40}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,white,transform shape]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,yscale=-1]
  \node at (80pt,5pt)  {$ \vec{F}=m\,\vec{a} $};
  \node at (50pt,10pt)  {$ \vec{F}=m \frac{\dd \vec{v}}{\dd t} 
  + \vec{v}\frac{\dd m}{\dd t} $};
  \node at (270pt,15pt)  {$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} $};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \node at (550pt,50pt)  {$ E=m\, c^2 $};
  \node at (520pt,100pt)  {$  \vec{F}_g=-F\,\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}\, \vec{e}_r $};
  \node at (550pt,150pt)  {$\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, \dd x = 2 $};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \node at (100pt,250pt)  {$\displaystyle \frac{\dd}{\dd x}\sin x=\cos x $};
  \node at (500pt,50pt)  {$\displaystyle \frac{\dd }{\dd x}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x} $};
  \node at (400pt,50pt)  {$  2\text{H}_2 + \text{O}_2 \xrightarrow{n,m}
  2\text{H}_2\text{O} $};
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
  \node at (200pt,150pt)  {$\displaystyle x = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}} $};
  \node at (350pt,300pt)  {$ \mathbf{X} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2 & \ldots \\
    x_3 & x_4 & \ldots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
    \end{pmatrix}$};
 \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I made no effort in arranging them nicely (yet I made some adjustments like switching to `pmatrix`, using `\overrightarrow` and making symbols like chemical elements and differential d's upright).

Comment: Interesting this form for the text perspective.

In Texworks I managed to configure it to work with pdflatex -shell-escape but not in TeXstudio, my favorite editor is TeXstudio, how to configure it to compile with pdflatex -shell-escape?

Comment: @SamuelDiaz I am sorry, I have no idea. I just use a text editor and run `pdflatex` from the terminal. (BTW, one can rotate the `tikz-3dplot` stuff further. Apart from a simple rotate key in the respective planes, one can use the `rotated coordinates` to rotate the full plane.)

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.